# LinearLayout doesn't fill the window

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set up 4 linear layouts: 2 vertical ones, side by side and 2 horizontal ones, arranged vertically.
This will give me a total of 3 vertical ones.

Then end goal is to have one layout for multiple screen sizes.
I set the weight of all 4 layouts to "1" to fill evenly.

I have tried to use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, but it does not fill the entire background.

If I use `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`, the layouts get clipped.

Here is screenshot of "wrap_content"
[image]

Here is screenshot of "fill_parent"
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff606060"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".SimpleRGB_Main" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Scene 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Scene 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Scene 3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Scene 4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Scene 5" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Scene 6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Scene7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Scene8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Scene9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Scene10" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="RECORD" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="PLAY" />
</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="RECORD1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="PLAY1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is what I am trying to attempt. Green is the layouts filled with buttons and or widgets.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ff606060"
android:weightSum="6"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
tools:context=".SimpleRGB_Main" >

<TableRow 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Scene 1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Scene 6" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Scene 2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Scene 7" />
 </TableRow>
<TableRow 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Scene 3" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Scene 8" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Scene 4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Scene 9" />
</TableRow>
  <TableRow 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Scene 5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Scene 10" />
 </TableRow>    
    <TableRow 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="RECORD" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="RECORD 1" />
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="PLAY " />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="PLAY 1" />
 </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

graphical view [image: op]

Comment: Thank you for suggestion on grid. The layout needs to be more flexable and placement of buttons is critical.  I am at a loss on how to proceed with a single layout for multiple size devices.

Comment: Well when issues comes to devices width and height, i suggest prepare some 3-4 rules or some standards layout and go for different xml. I know its painfull but no choice'.

Comment: I was able to get the table layout working. I will post results when completed. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Putting layout weights on children of `RelativeLayout` does not work. Weights only work on `LinearLayout` (that is, children of linear layout, not linear layout itself). Try starting by making your root layout linear, not RelativeLayout.

Comment: Weight also work on LinearLayouts, if they are themselves children of a LinearLayout ;)

Comment: Yes that's why I was trying to convey. I probably could be more clear about it

Comment: just to add my 2 cents... ;)

Comment: I made the change. All the linear layout are now arranged horizontally. Can it be setup for 2 horizontal and 2 vertical (stacked)?

Comment: you can but at some point you might want to switch to GridView